# Freddy JSON - copying the collection into a new array

Tags: json, swift, deserialization

In Freddy JSON with Swift, an extension exists to...

"Create an instance by copying each element of the `collection` into a new `Array`", as defined in the Freddy notes below...

```
public init<Collection>(_ collection: Collection) where Collection : Collection, Collection.Element == Freddy.JSON

// Create an instance initialized with `elements`.
public init(arrayLiteral elements: Freddy.JSON...)
```

Given that I already have the data, how is this initializer used? Transforming the data in the usual way as below is fine, but I am not sure on the syntax to copy the data as a collection.

```
let json = try JSON(data: data)
```

If it helps, my intention is to get the content of each array and create a new object from it.

```
[{
    "array1": [{
        "array1keys": "example",
    }],
    "array2": [{
        "array2keys": "example"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Codable protocol provided out of the box by Swift?

Given your json

```
let data = """
[
    {
        "array1": [
        {
            "array1keys": "example",
        }
        ],
        "array2": [
        {
            "array2keys": "example"
        }
        ]
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

We can define a type representing your data

```
typealias SubElement = [String:String]
typealias Element = [String:[SubElement]]
typealias Response = [Element]
```

And finally we can decode your json

```
if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
    print(response)
}

[["array1": [["array1keys": "example"]], "array2": [["array2keys": "example"]]]]
```

> Usually I would suggest to define a struct conform to `Codable` which makes the code much more easy to read. But in this case this is not possible since there are no fields with a fixed name.